# Sharing code in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What is the prefered way to share code between AWS Lambda functions?

I have a structure like this:

- functions

  - a

    - node_modules
    - index.js
    - package.json
  - b

    - node_modules
    - index.js
    - package.json
  - c

    - node_modules
    - index.js
    - package.json

This let every function keep its own node_modules and I can package the whole thing with the CLI.

But what about custom code that needs to be shared?

I can `require("../mylibrary")` but the package command would still not include it.

Comment: Are you using `serverless` framework?

Comment: I'm using AWS SAM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As dmigo mentioned already it's possible with Lambda layers. Here is some [SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model) template code for using the Lambda Layer Code:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs8.10

MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
        CodeUri: a/
        Handler: index.handler
        Layers:
        - !Ref MySharedLayer
MySharedLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
        LayerName: SharedLayer
        Description: Some code to share with the other lambda functions
        ContentUri: layer/
        CompatibleRuntimes:
            - nodejs8.10
        RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

Comment: How do you then use the function inside your lambda function? I tried just importing `SharedLayer` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

Now you can use [Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) to share libraries and code between your Functions. You can create a Layer from a zip file the same way you do that for a Function.

The layer package will look more or less like this:

```
my-layer.zip
└ nodejs/node_modules/mylibrary
```

If you create your Functions on top of this Layer then in the code it can be referenced like this:

```
const shared = require('mylibrary');
```

It is worth noticing that Layers support versioning and relate to Functions as many-to-many. Which makes them second npm.

Answer (score 1):

Try serverless framework, you can use the include/exclude artifacts without having to write your own scripts.

[checkout serverless.com](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging)

I also use private node packages, but they need to be installed before sls deploy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Lambda is, you have to deploy a ZIP-file, so all your code needs to be accesible from one root directory.

I solved this with a script that copies my shared code to all the Lambda-function directories before I archive every single function and upload them.

Symlinks are probably also possible.

Comment: I tried symlinks and they didn't work for me, though there does seem to be a pull request that would add support for symlinks to the aws-cli. Hopefully it gets merged someday. https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/2901

Comment: It is merged now.